Having issues connecting GridDB to SQL Workbench
My system's version is Ubuntu 22.04 running through WSL 2 on Windows 11 and I am using the community edition for GridDB version 5.5.0.
I cannot connect to griddb using SQL Workbench, I tried the connection like in the tutorial video
GridDB 101: Chapter 2 -- SQL Workbench/J
and it was just hanging without a timeout.
The string I used to connect was this: jdbc//127.0.0.1:41999/myCluster/public.

After going around and checking the config files I found out the information I needed.
The default port for a fixed list cluster seems to be different from that of a multicast, but you can find the port by going to the following file for cluster config from gs_adm user home folder:
cat gs_cluster.json
And picking the port for SQL from there(20001 seems to be the default), the connection was successful. That file should be referred to for connections and ports instead of following the video one to one since the default port seems to vary by the notification mode. By changing the port number in the connection string I was able to connect successfully.
